# Input data given to 'drone' is not a valid GeoJSON object

Tags: javascript, mapbox, geojson, fetch-api, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to render a polygon from a webservice to a mapbox map as a proof of concept.

My webservice gives me the following geojson with some mock data:

```
{"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[[[9.750441312789917,52.350087018909683],[9.7523081302642822,52.34896634765532],[9.7523403167724609,52.350106679555289],[9.750441312789917,52.350087018909683]]]},"properties":{"test1":"value1"}}]}
```

But mapbox gives me the error I can see in the browser console:
Input data given to 'drone' is not a valid GeoJSON object.

http://geojson.io and http://geojsonlint.com/ understand that geojson my webservice was generating.
It is send as content-type "text/plain; charset=utf-8"
because as application/json it gets a lot of \ characters, which is not working.

Below you can see the html code I am using for this test.

So what am I doing wrong here?

I checked that the geojson is correctly formatted and I added the same geojson directly as a source and it worked. See below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <title>Add multiple geometries from one GeoJSON source</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
    <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
    <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v1.2.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
    <style>
        body {
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            bottom: 0;
            width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>

    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>
        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.xxxxxx';
        var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: "map",
            style: "mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11",
            center: [9.754206, 52.355394],
            zoom: 14
        });

        var url = 'https://localhost:44337/api/resource';

        map.on('load', function () {

            map.addSource('drone', { type: 'geojson', data: url });

            map.addLayer({
                "id": "drone",
                "type": "fill",
                "source": "drone",
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': '#088',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

I expect that there is some polygon on the map, like it is if I put the geojson directly into the code:

```
        map.on('load', function () {

            map.addLayer({
                'id': 'maine',
                'type': 'fill',
                'source': {
                    'type': 'geojson',
                    'data': 


                    {
                        "type": "FeatureCollection",
                        "features": [
                            {
                                "type": "Feature",
                                "geometry": {
                                    "type": "Polygon",
                                    "coordinates": [
                                        [
                                            [
                                                9.750441312789917,
                                                52.350087018909683
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                9.7523081302642822,
                                                52.34896634765532
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                9.7523403167724609,
                                                52.350106679555289
                                            ],
                                            [
                                                9.750441312789917,
                                                52.350087018909683
                                            ]
                                        ]
                                    ]
                                },
                                "properties": {
                                    "test1": "value1"
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }

                },
                'layout': {},
                'paint': {
                    'fill-color': '#088',
                    'fill-opacity': 0.8
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I reckon mapboxgl is doing call this, but if it helps, this is the asp.net core backend snippet:

```
        // GET: api/resource
        [HttpGet]
        public JsonResult GetResources()
        {
            var poly = _context.Resources.First().Polygon;

            AttributesTable attributes = new AttributesTable();
            attributes.Add("test1", "value1");
            IFeature feature = new Feature(poly, attributes);
            FeatureCollection featureCollection = new FeatureCollection(new Collection<IFeature> { feature });
            var gjw = new GeoJsonWriter();
            gjw.SerializerSettings.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
            string actual = gjw.Write(featureCollection);

            return new JsonResult(actual);
        }
```

I am using NetTopologySuite.
And poly is a SQL Server Geography type Polygon.

EDIT: Ok I figured it out myself:
I had to do this:
`return Content(actual, "application/json", Encoding.UTF8);`
and use ContentResult as a return type.

My Json seemed to get serialized twice, since it got too many characters.
Ah and the fetch and response.json() parsing exside proposed is not needed with the correct geojson response. But it is also working with it. ;)
Thanks though.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should try to fetch your geoJSON from your API manually and see if that works, passing a URL as a geoJSON object to mapbox seems to work as well, but maybe something is wrong with your API, so I would do a manual `fetch` and see if anything goes wrong. Furthermore, you should definitely change your content-type header back to `application/json`, the following snippet assumes you did that!

```js
map.on('load', async function() {

  let response = await fetch(url);

  let data = await (
    response.headers.get('content-type').includes('json')
    ? response.json() // this will parse your JSON if the proper content-type header is set!
    : response.text()
  );

  map.addSource('drone', { type: 'geojson', data: data });

  map.addLayer({
    "id": "drone",
    "type": "fill",
    "source": "drone",
    'layout': {},
    'paint': {
      'fill-color': '#088',
      'fill-opacity': 0.8
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for your reply,
unfortunately now I get this:
```
Object { status: 404, url: "http://localhost/%7B%22type%22:%22FeatureCollection%22,%22features%22:[%7B%22type%22:%22Feature%22,%22geometry%22:%7B%22type%22:%22Polygon%22,%22coordinates%22:[[[9.750441312789917,52.350087018909683],[9.7523081302642822,52.34896634765532],[9.7523403167724609,52.350106679555289],[9.750441312789917,52.350087018909683]]]%7D,%22properties%22:%7B%22test1%22:%22value1%22%7D%7D]%7D", name: "e", message: "Not Found", stack: "" }
evented.js:136:20
```
It now wants to get the geojson from this weird URL

Comment: And why is this example working?
https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/live-geojson/
Because https://wanderdrone.appspot.com/ gives you a html page containing the geojson?

Comment: wanderdrone definitely gives back geoJSON, but as you can see from your error, something with your API is wrong, make sure that your API is working properly, which is exactly where the manual fetching can help with debugging!

Comment: If you check the header, it says "content-type 
text/html; charset=utf-8" for wanderdrone. That's not even json right?
I don't know what's wrong with my API. As I said, both services understand that geojson my API give me...

Comment: "That's not even json right?" the response data is json, the server just sends the wrong content-type for whatever reason. But the error you get (I don't know with which code though) is a 404, e.g. the URL you query on your API is not routed correctly and therefore can't be found!

Comment: Mouseover the localhost URL above. He is trying to use the json as a link. localhost/<geojsoncontent>.... Don't know why this is happening...

Comment: you need to share your code, it's impossible to tell without!